# How to handle Exception and return proper HTTP code in Spring webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, exception, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method which gives response using Mono.fromfuture(result) and which throws CustomException with 400 as status.
Now in my service class, when I call that method, the error and code I am throwing there is not getting propagated to my client(postman). Only the message is what I am seeing.

I am getting  this below format: -

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-01T11:13:32.748+0000",
    "path": "/some_url",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Unable to fetch Response"
}
```

Expectation (what I want to achieve) : -

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-01T11:13:32.748+0000",
    "path": "/some_url",
    "status": 400,                           // (my own status)
    "error": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",             // (my own error)
    "message": "Unable to fetch Response"
}
```

My Code:-

```
public Mono<ResponseObject> fetchResponse(arg) {

   return Mono.just(somedata which will give exception)
      .flatMap(k -> callExternalService(k))
      .onErrorMap(e -> Mono.error(
            new BusinessException("Unable to fetch Response", e))

       */* e here is giving :-
        "code" : 400,
        "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT" */*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation of the [`Response`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/Response.html) class?

You can create a `Response` of your own, using the static methods in the doc, and send it, instead of `Mono.error`, in the `onErrorMap`.

You have to return something like below:

```
ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(klass, Klass.class);

ServerResponse.status(status).build();//read doc and set for yourself
```

You can also check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors).

Comment: Response is not a predefined class. Its my own object (edited now to ResponseObject). Can you suggest any other way ?

Comment: The router needs a ServerResponse. Pass on the ServerResponse or Response. Check the docs.